# Skipping the next instruction in mips32

Tags: assembly, mips

Suppose I want to develop a psuedoinstruction in MIPS that skips the next instruction after I call this skip instruction say
`skip $s0`.

I thought maybe I could use `$jr` on `$s0`, but I would need to change the address of `$s0`.

How could I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to develop a psuedoinstruction in MIPS that skips the next instruction

The simpler is to use a "branch" that is always verified.

```
beqc $0,$0,2
```

will replace `PC` by `PC+(2*4)` if $0==$0 (ie always) and skip next instruction.

This is a trick frequently used to process if-then-else

```
if(a1)
   a2=3;
else
   a3=4;
```

```
      beqc  $a1, $0, else
      addi $a2, $0, 3
      beqc  $0,  $0, 2 ; go to end of if then else
else: addi $a3, $0, 4
      # end of if-then else
```

`beqc`is a delay less branch introduced in mips64-v6 (along many other branch/jump with zero delay slots).

With older versions of the mips ISA, it is not possible to skip next instruction, as *all* branches execute the following instruction. To skip the second next instruction, the idea is the same.

```
beq $0,$0,2       ; delayed branch. execute next instruction and if test 
                  ;   is true (ie always) go to pc+4+2*4
add $0, $0, $0    ; aka nop (because of the delay slot)
xxx $a1, $a2, $a3 ; this instruction will be skipped
yyy $t1, $t2, $t3 ; and this instruction will be executed
```

Comment: _"will replace PC by PC+(2*4) if $0==$0 (ie always) and skip next instruction"_ Unless you're on a real MIPS CPU which has delayed branching.

Comment: Right. I mostly use mips for teaching on simulators with nice interfaces and branch delay slots deactivated, but most real mips cpu have delayed branches.   Recent version of mips64 (v6) introduced new "compact" delayless branches. I update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think maybe it should be `beq $0,$0,2` in the last example. The offset is relative to the address of the instruction in the delay slot.

Comment: You are right. I double checked, because most internet sources indicate that bxx does 'pc<-pc+offset<<2', but MIPS documents, that are authoritative, indicate that this is computed at i+1 instruction.

Comment: Are you calling `PC` the address of the branch instruction?  Since fetch has already incremented its fetch address to fetch the next instruction, you could consider PC=start of next instruction while any instruction is decoding or executing. (Or maybe I mixed something up here).  Relative branches work like this on most ISAs, e.g. x86.  Anyway, I think it would be clearer to express the formula in terms of `PC = branch_address + 4*2`, if that's what it really is, to avoid any confusion over the value of PC when the formula is applied.

Comment: Yes PC is the PC of the branch instruction. It does not describes what happens in the hardware (and you are right PC will be incremented during fetch), but what is the final result of the instruction. While many ISA consider PC as the address of next instruction, the MIPS documentation specifies that it concerns current instruction : "PC : The Program Counter value. During the instruction time of an instruction, this is the address of the instruction word".